# How to make sphinx-apidoc, doctest and -W option play together nicely?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest, sphinx-apidoc

My current pipeline looks something like the following:

```
sphinx-build -b doctest -d docs/build/doctrees docs docs/build/doctest
sphinx-apidoc -f -o docs/ src/my_package
sphinx-build -b html -d docs/build/doctrees docs docs/build/html
```

The `index.rst` file contains `my_package` in the toctree to include the generated API docs. The generated API docs are not under version control and get freshly generated with every pipeline run.

I would like to add the `-W` option to the `sphinx-build` calls to turn warnings into errors. However, I get the warning `index.rst:5:toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'my_package'` on the doctest call. I can run `sphinx-apidoc` first but then the doctest call raises `docs/modules.rst:document isn't included in any toctree`. I can add the `--no-toc` option to sphinx-apidoc but then the doctests fail because they apparently also run on the .rst files generated by sphinx-apidoc and can not find imported functions if `modules.rst` is missing. Excluding `modules.rst` via `exclude_patterns` in my `conf.py` also breaks the doctest call.

How can I configure my pipeline so that I can call both `sphinx-build` calls with `-W` and still get the auto-generated API docs?